# cant find the end of page by selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

мне нужно прокрутить страницу видео на ютубе до конца. не могу определить конец страницы т.е когда прокручивание должен остановиться.
I need to scroll page to the end,but i cant just defiend the end of the page!

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEjpJz-JIzzaO0KMF8HgAew/videos'
headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36",
        'x-youtube-client-name': '1',
        'x-youtube-client-version': '2.20200429.03.00',
        }
def get_source_html():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\youtube_parser\geckodriver.exe')
    driver.get(url=url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    try:
        time.sleep(3)
        i = 1
        while True:
            i += 1
            # Use send_keys(Keys.HOME) to scroll up to the top of pag
            if driver.find_element_by_tag_name(''):#here should be if for stop scroling
                with open("source-page.html","w",encoding='utf-8') as file:
                    file.write(driver.page_source)
                    break
            else:
                driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)#this code is scroling
                print('still scroling',i)


    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
def main():
    get_source_html()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. контент динамический, нельзя сразу получить всю высоту страницы, так:

```
h = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight;')
```

А на ютубе можно на высоту окна смещаться

```
h_prev = 0
while True:
    h = driver.execute_script('return window.innerHeight + window.scrollY;')
    driver.execute_script(f'window.scrollTo(0,{h});')
    time.sleep(1)
    if h == h_prev:
        break
    h_prev = h
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! не понял как это работает но это работает!!